# iPhone4 won't connect to the MonoTouch debugger after downloading new provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ipad, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I downloaded a new provisioning profile from Apple which has support for my iPad and iPhone and now when I try to compile debug|iphone the debugger no longer attaches to the iphone.

Basically what happens is it uploads it to the device successfully and the window shows up asking me to run the iPhone app so the debugger can connect. So I do that but the debugger never connects, the iPhone vibrates and starts running the app.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging works over WiFi.  Both your phone and your Mac need to have WiFi enabled and be on the same network.  The buzz when your app starts means that you are running a debug build, but it is unable to connect to the debugger.